# How can I get the resource group name from within Service Fabric on Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-group

My service can be placed on different resource groups, but needs to know the name of the resource group in order to request information about the VM Scale Sets it's running on.
How do I get the name of the Resource Group which the Fabric is in from within the Fabric?

Comment: What does your service need to know about the VMSS it's running on?

Comment: I need a list of the VM names in each VMSS that the Fabric includes. This is not the same as the list of node names in the Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

If you uniquely tag your resource group, and configure the sf application to know that  tag, you might be able to query the resource groups and filter by tag. You could use a Service Principal to access the Resource manager.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think this workaround would be a good solution in my case. I'm looking for a more direct solution, which doesn't require additional infrastructure/setup changes.