# How to find at runtime to which Azure cluster your service fabric is deployed

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-service-fabric

I have a .Net Service Fabric application which is deployed to different Azure clusters.
Is there some API to know during run time in which Azure cluster region my code is running at?

The motivation behind this is that I want to change code behavior based on which region my code is running at.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158515/5946937 combined with the environment variable that holds the node name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference

Answer (score 0):

In azure, you can use the [Instance Metadada Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) to query details about the VM where you application is running.

Something like this:

`curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-12-01"`

Will return the **compute** information with `location` attribute:

```
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "westus",
    "name": "avset2",
    "offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "placementGroupId": "",
    "platformFaultDomain": "1",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "1",
    "publisher": "Canonical",
    "resourceGroupName": "myrg",
    "sku": "16.04-LTS",
    "subscriptionId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tags": "",
    "version": "16.04.201708030",
    "vmId": "13f56399-bd52-4150-9748-7190aae1ff21",
    "vmScaleSetName": "",
    "vmSize": "Standard_D1",
    "zone": "1"
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.1.2.5",
              "publicIpAddress": "X.X.X.X"
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "10.1.2.0",
              "prefix": "24"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": "000D3A36DDED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the only way is HTTP request? I would have expected to have an API exposed to get this info

Comment: This is an API, provided by the service mentioned above. You could make an REST call using http client